# Postgresql randomly starting to complain about grouping clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

For almost a year, I have been using this sql to report on the rank of game profiles, based on the number of days that a game has been above the rank of 10:

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, P.rank, COUNT(P.id)

FROM application_classes_models_gameprofile P

LEFT JOIN application_classes_models_gamedeveloper D ON D.id = P."developerId"

LEFT JOIN application_classes_models_gameprofileposition PP ON 
PP."gameProfileId" = P.id AND 
PP.position <= 10 AND
PP.position > 0

WHERE 
P.inactive = false AND
D."excludeFromRanking" = false AND
P.rank <= 10 AND 
P.rank > 0

GROUP BY P.id

ORDER BY COUNT(P.id) DESC
```

Grouping is always a big of a pain in postgresql, but the above sql has been working fine for almost a year, returning the expected results.

Yesterday, I had an issue with the game profile table which forced me to have to restore a backup, for that table. I did so using `pg_restore -v --clean -t application_classes_models_gameprofile < backup.bak`.

This morning, when we ran our reports, postgresql came back with the error:

```
column "p.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Just to clarify, this sql has been running for almost a year, and the above error has never appeared for this specific sql query, however, it seems that after we have cleaned and restored the game profile table we're getting the above error...

I know that I can solve the problem by fixing the sql query to remove the name/rank, but I worry if there is a deeper issue here... so does anyone know why the above might happen?

Postgresal version is 9.6, running on debian 9

Comment: Did you change the primary key of the table `application_classes_models_gameprofile` to something else than just `id`? Or did the restore maybe remove it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't believe I didn't think to check that, I just assumed the backup/restore would have included the constraints/indexes but I just checked at it didn't! So that's exactly what the problem was. Many thanks to you sir for pointing that out!

As for the quoted names, the above is the back-end of an ORM, and the fields have to match the casing of the model properties. I agree, it's a pain but once you get in the habit of doing it, it's not too bad!

Comment: `pg_dump` does include primary keys, apparently your backup procedure needs some testing

Comment: yeah @a_horse_with_no_name I thought that too... we're going to look into both the backup/restore to try and see where it failed to carry those over. I'm glad though I didn't just "fix" the above sql, that could have become a serious problem at some point! Thanks again